# Django list off item in which category containing some same item

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hi I have a model named **ITEMS** for some items

**ITEMS** = item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7

how can I do this...

each item from ITEMS contains 4 categories **uncategorized, cat1, cat2, cat3**

and each category contain some items from ITEMS model except item in witch this category comes

For example...

item1 has 4 categories uncategorized, cat1, cat2, cat3

uncategorized = item7

cat1 = item2, item3

cat2 = item4, item5

cat3 = item6, item7

Those all categories cam be contained any of this item except item1 witch contains all 4 categories

how can I achieve this type of model structure in Django..?

if there is no such model. how can I do by own logic..?

Thanks in advance if you need a more detail reply at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You should make another model named CATEGORIES and then you can establish a many to many relationship between ITEMS and CATEGORIES. Then you can use following code to get items of one category or categories of one item.

```
item = ITEMS.objects.get(id='item1')
item_categories = item.categories.all()
```

or

```
category = CATEGORY.objects.get(id='cat1')
category_items = category.items.all()
```

[Django Many to Many relationship reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: I used but the problem is for all item category items remain same. I need a verity of selection for each item category

Comment: In your question, you have provided different items for each category. Here you are saying they are same. Clarify it properly, what you want to achieve?

Comment: My problem with many-to-many relationship is...when i add item to any category its reflect on every ITEM's category. istaed of this i want  when i add item to Item1 its add only in item 1 category not in all.

Comment: How are you adding? Post some code, so I can guide you further

Comment: I want this type of model OR logic for my android application cross-marketing
I have 10 android apps. in my app I have 3 advertising sections (sec1, sec2, sec3). when someone opens an app in these 3 sections shows a list of apps(my own app from the list of 10). I want to make website for adding and removing apps in these three section so when I add or remove this app my app fetch detail from database and show apps on the list.

all app has same 3 sections but section contain a different list for all apps. and all apps have 3 sections with different selected apps (from the list of 10).